# Necessary and sufficient conditions for $ax^2+bx+c$ to be factorizable...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What are necessary and sufficient conditions for $ax^2+bx+c$ to be factorizable involving just integer coefficients?

We already know that this expression is factorizable if $b^2-4ac$ is a perfect square,([$ax^2+bx+c$ is factorizable if...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844477/prove-that-if-b2-4ac-k2-then-ax2bxc-is-factorizable))but in this case can we be sure that all the coefficients are just integers??

Comment: Assuming you mean factorizable over $\mathbb{Q}$, a necessary condition is given by Eisenstein's criterion.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 No,I mean just factorizable over $\Bbb{Z}$

Comment: By [Gauss's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_lemma_%28polynomial%29), if you can factor a nonconstant polynomial (with integer coefficients) over the rationals, you can factor it over the integers.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you dear,I got it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Is there any algorithm for converting a rational factorization of a polynomial into an integer factorization?

Comment: Put everything over a common denominator, and take out common integer factors of the numerators.  Denominators should cancel with the factors of the numerators.

Comment: @RobertIsrael What about this: $(x+\frac13)(x+1)=(\frac{3x+1}{3})(x+1)$?!!

Comment: $x^2 + \frac{4}{3} x + \frac{1}{3}$ does not have integer coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Israel's comment:

> By Gauss's lemma, if you can factor a nonconstant polynomial (with integer coefficients) over the rationals, you can factor it over the integers.

And as you point out, it factors over the rationals just in case $b^2 - 4ac$ is a perfect square.
Therefore it factors over the integers just in case $b^2 - 4ac$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Yes,in fact my question had been already answered by Gauss's lemma! which I didn't know about.