# To what sets must $a,b,c$ belong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratics

I just thought of kind of a cool number theory/algebra problem.

> Given that $$\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\in\Bbb N$$
>   To which sets must $a,b,c$ belong?

It is obvious that $$b^2-4ac\in\left\{x^2|x\in\Bbb N\right\}$$
But beyond that, I do not know what to do. May I have some help?

**Edit:**

To make things more interesting, what if $a,b,c\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: Note that $a,b,c$ need not be integers. So this is no Diophantine equation. So it is a little bit "less cool". We just write $b^2-4ac=x^2$, so that $a=(b^2-d^2)/(4c)$ for $c$ nonzero. Then choose $b,c\in \Bbb R$ and $d \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: But what if $a,b,c$ *were* integers?

Comment: So, should we let $a,b,c\in\mathbb N$?

Answer (score 3):

all triples $a,b,c$ that work are given by
$$ ax^2 + b x y + c y^2 = (sx+ty)(ux+vy) \; , \;   $$
$$  a = su, $$
$$  b = sv+tu,  $$
$$  c = tv .  $$
When those happen,
$$ b^2 - 4ac = s^2 v^2 + 2 stuv + t^2 u^2 - 4 stuv =s^2 v^2 - 2 stuv + t^2 u^2 = (sv-tu)^2 $$

see [Prove that if $b^2-4ac=k^2$ then $ax^2+bx+c$ is factorizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844477/prove-that-if-b2-4ac-k2-then-ax2bxc-is-factorizable/1844995#1844995)

Comment: Okay, so to which sets do $s,v,t,u$ belong?

Comment: @clathratus integers