# Binary Quadratic Form representing an integer with constraint on discriminant

Tags: quadratic-forms

Let $f(x,y) = ax^2 + 2bxy + cy^2$ be a binary quadratic form. The discriminant of this is $D = -b^2 + ac$.

Let $N$ be a positive integer. I would like to construct a binary quadratic form $f(x,y)$ that represents $N$ with the constraint that $-\lfloor {\sqrt{N}}\rfloor < D < \lfloor {\sqrt{N}}\rfloor$.

**What I have tried so far:**
Fix $y = 1$ to get $f(x,1) = ax^2 + 2bx + c$. Now, for $x \ge 2 \in \mathbb Z$, get a base-$x$ representation of $N$, but stop after the second division and collect the quotient and remainders. Verify the coefficient of $x$ in the base-$x$ representation is even (i.e., must be $2b$) and then check $-\lfloor {\sqrt{N}}\rfloor < D < \lfloor {\sqrt{N}}\rfloor$. If conditions not met, try the next $x$. While the procedure produces $(a,b,c)$ that yields a binary quadratic form that represents $N$, it doesn't necessarily meet the $-\lfloor {\sqrt{N}}\rfloor < D < \lfloor {\sqrt{N}}\rfloor$ constraint.

The other approach I have tried is quite similar. Fix $c$. We then have $N - c = ax^2 + 2bx = x(ax+2b)$. Therefore, $x|(N-c)$. This approach is suitable to narrow down the $x$ to just the divisors of $N - c$, but unsuitable when $N$ gets large (due to the need for factoring).

How does one go about achieving this, keeping in mind that $N$ is large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to work with the continued fraction for $\sqrt N$

if $\frac{p}{q}$ is a convergent for $\sqrt N$  then  $p^2 - N q^2$  is quite small in absolute value (smaller than $2 \sqrt N  $ as I recall).

If you go all the way through you get
$$  p^2 - N q^2 = 1  $$
with $q \geq 1.$

Then let
$$f(x,y) = ax^2 + 2bxy + cy^2 = q^2 x^2 + 2pxy + N y^2$$

Just so you know:  if you go through the whole  continued fraction business, as above, you have found a quick way to factor $N.$   [I put that here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844477/prove-that-if-b2-4ac-k2-then-ax2bxc-is-factorizable/1844995#1844995) For your purpose, it is likely that stopping early, finding $p^2 - N q^2 = r$  with $|r|$ small and $r$ not a square may be enough.

Plot twist:  I took $N = 32045 = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 29.$   Going all the way to $x^2 - 32045 y^2 = 1$ gave the trivial factors $1 \cdot 32045.$  However, there are also (primitive)  representations $u^2 - 32045 v^2 = 4$  which give different pairs of factors