Factoring quadratics: reducing to monic case [AC method]
Is it true that if for some quadratic $ax^2 +  bx + c$ (where $a, b, c$ are integers) there exists 2 integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m + n = b$ and $mn = ac$, then there exists integers $A, B, C, D$ such that $(Ax + B)(Cx + D) = ax^2 +  bx + c$?
I'm able to prove the converse that if that $ax^2 + bx + c = (Ax + B)(Cx + D)$ (where $a, b, c$ are real and $A, B, C, D$ are integers), then there exists there exists 2 integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m + n = b$ and $mn = ac$, namely where $m = AD$ and $n = BC$. This is because $a = AC$, $b = AD + BC$, and $c = BD$ (which also implies $a, b, c$ are integers), meaning $m + n = AD + BC = b$ and $mn = (AD)(BC) = (AC)(BD) = ac$ .
However, when I try to prove the previous claim, I get that I can factor the quadratic as either $(mx + c)(\frac{n}{c}x + 1)$ or $(nx + c)(\frac{m}{c}x + 1)$, however how can I show either n/c or m/c is an integer? Do we need some use of number theory or clever algebra that I'm not seeing here or something?
I'm just trying to better understand basic factoring techniques I learned in grade school but never really thought why do they work or make sense. Since with the claim I was able to prove, it's contrapositive tells me if you can't find 2 integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m + n = b$ and $mn = ac$, then there doesn't not exist 4 integers $A, B, C, D$ such that $(Ax + B)(Cx + D) = ax^2 +  bx + c$ (correct?)
But then this doesn't prove to me the claim I ask about since an implication's converse is not necessarily true. Hence I kindly need some help here.
By the way this was inspired by Khan Academy's "proof" (don't think it actually proves my claim I'm asking about) that I ironically never learned about in middle school when 1st learning this technique (maybe I wasn't paying attention, I don't know): https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratics-multiplying-factoring/x2f8bb11595b61c86:factor-quadratics-grouping/a/factoring-quadratics-leading-coefficient-not-1!

your first paragraph is off.  Success is when there are rational numbers $r,s$  with $r+s = -b/a$ and $rs = c/a$

@WillJagy well that's referring to the roots of the quadratic, but I'm just referring to 2 integers that help split the bx^1 term into 2 terms and then let us factor by grouping

If $c$ is composite then the qudaratic might not need be factorised as $(?x+1)(?x+c)$.

@Lucenaposition I think I see what you're saying, but then how should I split c for the case where c is composite?

if the discriminant, $d = b^2 - 4ac$  is a perfect square, then there is a factoring such as you wish. If $d$  is not a square there is no factoring.

I put a method at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844477/prove-that-if-b2-4ac-k2-then-ax2bxc-is-factorizable/1844995#1844995

This is known as the  AC-method, see here in the linked dupe for a proof and generalizations. $\ \ $

The factoring is $a(x+\frac{m}{a})(x+\frac{n}{a})$  . We need to show that there exist integers $p,q$ with $a=pq$ such that $\frac{m}{q}$ and $\frac{n}{p}$ are integers, ie. we can "split" $a$ accordingly as: $a(x+\frac{m}{a})(x+\frac{n}{a}) = (px+\frac{m}{q})(qx+\frac{n}{p})$. This can be stated as a divisivility problem: $(a|mn) \Rightarrow (\exists p, q); ((pq =a) ;\land ;  (p|m); \land ; (q|n))$.

@user3257842 That proof is already in the linked dupe. $\ \ $

@WillJagy No, the first paragraph is correct - see here in the linked dupe.

@Bob The reduction is from the general (nonmonic) case to the monic case. Hence the title.

@BillDubuque where is the reduction being performed?

See said linked answwr in the dupe.
